# What does VTK 5.6.1 implement OpenGL Version?

Tags: android, vtk

I want to know [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) Version that VTK 5.6.1 implement because I want to create android application that use vtk.I will use VTK visualize DICOM image and present them on screen.
I know Android OS implement OpenGL ES but I don't know VTK 5.6.1 OpenGL version.if VTK OpenGL's version is 4.1 that support [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES),it mean I can use vtk 5.6.1 to create android application,right.

Thanking you for assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly related to your other question about using VTK on Android. As I said in response to that question, VTK does not currently support Android (or other embedded systems). The base OpenGL version used by much of VTK is 1.1, but quite a few of the classes test for various OpenGL extensions and use them optionally. Porting VTK to OpenGL ES (1.x or 2.0) is non-trivial, but some initial work has begun. See [this post](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/VTK-for-OpenGL-ES-eventually-Android-td3311335.html) for a little more background.

I have been doing some work on the iOS and Android platforms, largely concerned with using OpenGL ES 2.0 from C++ on both platforms (NDK on Android). The results were promising, but it will take time to port a significant portion of VTK. OpenGL ES 2.0 and Open GL 2.1 are quite similar in their API, but they are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your purpose/context is regarding using VTK on android, but if you are talking about reading in VTK files and rendering the objects on android, I can give you an explanation (and perhaps some code) on how to do that. I'm currently programming an app that takes in a legacy-VTK ASCII file and renders the image using opengl. Like Marcus said, its non-trivial, and a little bit rough, but I used basic indexOf and tokenizer/split methods to search through the vtk file for the vertices, indices, normals, and text. coords and put them into buffers. I see this is an old thread, so I'm not going to explain any further/give out code unless someone wants it.